# overloaded increment's return value

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In his The C++ Programming Language Stroustrup gives the following example for inc/dec overloading:

```
class Ptr_to_T {
    T* p;
    T* array ;
    int size;
public:
    Ptr_to_T(T* p, T* v, int s); // bind to array v of size s, initial value p
    Ptr_to_T(T* p); // bind to single object, initial value p
    Ptr_to_T& operator++(); // prefix
    Ptr_to_T operator++(int); // postfix
    Ptr_to_T& operator--(); // prefix
    Ptr_to_T operator--(int); // postfix
    T&operator*() ; // prefix
}
```

Why prefix operators return by reference while postfix operators return by value?

Thanks.

Comment: should that be:
Ptr_to_T& operator--(); // prefix
Ptr_to_T operator--(int); // postfix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand better, you have to imagine (or look at) how are these operators implemented. Typically, the prefix operator++ will be written more or less like this:

```
MyType& operator++()
{
    // do the incrementation
    return *this;
}
```

Since `this` has been modified "in-place", we can return a reference to the instance in order to avoid a useless copy.

Now, here's the code for the postfix operator++:

```
MyType operator++(int)
{
    MyType tmp(*this); // create a copy of 'this'
    ++(*this); // use the prefix operator to perform the increment
    return tmp; // return the temporary
}
```

As the postfix operator returns a temporary, it has to return it by value (otherwise, you'll get a dangling reference).

The [C++ Faq Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.14) also has a paragraph on the subject.

Comment: I get on this:
CircularInt.cpp: In member function ‘CircularInt& CircularInt::operator++(int)’:
CircularInt.cpp:48:17: warning: reference to local variable ‘result’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     CircularInt result(*this);   // make a copy for result

Comment: @Tomer: You cannot return a reference to a local variable because that variable will be destroyed when leaving the function, so the caller would end up with a reference to a variable that no longer exists. You need to return a value and not a reference.

Answer (score 17):

The postfix operator returns a copy of the value before it was incremented, so it pretty much has to return a temporary. The prefix operator does return the current value of the object, so it can return a reference to, well, its current value.

Comment: combined with the fact that you can't return a temporary by reference, this is a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I use overloaded preincrement to increment a private member. Doesn't returning a reference to a private member turns the ++private_var expression to an lvalue thus making it possible to modify the private member directly?

Comment: You don't return the reference to private member, but to your class' object. (because the outside world was incrementing your object, not it's private field).